# What's the difference between 2 folders '.git/origin' and .git/refs/remotes/origin?

Tags: git, directory, duplicates

I cannot reproduce steps but it happened that at some point I've got in my repo two folders. One is .git/origin another is .git/refs/remotes/origin. Both have 2 files: `HEAD` and `master`, but the content is different.

```
.git/origin/HEAD content is "ref: origin/master"
.git/origin/master - 604a5954c8bacda7e9079bf4d13921b31b8eddf0

.git/origin/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD - ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
.git/origin/refs/remotes/origin/master - 2bc80f9562eb7955ab5f487a61e02e74eafed24d
```

commit `604a` is already not reachable from any branch/tag

`git branch -a` shows

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

`git remote show origin` shows

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/. . . . . .git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/. . . . . .git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote main
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Why does the folder .git/origin appear?
Where and why does it point to?

Comment: `.git/origin` should not exist. It was created by some mistake (yours, or some third party software, or something). The `.git` directory should have one file for `HEAD`, an `index` if there are files checked out, optionally some additional files for other `*_HEAD` instances, a `description` file, a `refs` directory, an `objects` directory, and a few other directories, and little else, until you start adding working trees when it gains `.git/worktree/` for instance.

Comment: @torek seeing your SO reputation in the Git area I trust your answer. I understand that it's much more difficult to prove that something does not exist rather its existence, however, I am still not 100% satisfied. Maybe you could give some examples when people faced the same issue as mine having `.git/origin` folder? Understanding their circumstances I might understand mine and avoid the same mistake in the future. Originally my repo was created with Visual Studio (C#) and recently I switched to VS Code.

Comment: I've never seen it myself, but it would happen if some software was trying to write to `.git/refs/remotes/origin/` and dropped the `refs/remotes/` part. Software could do this by running `git update-ref origin/master <hash>` for instance. The `git branch` command is "friendlier", tacking on the appropriate prefix for a local branch (`refs/heads/`) or a remote-tracking name (`refs/remotes/`) but correctly-written software *should* use `git update-ref` and supply the full name. I'm just guessing as to what happened, though, having not seen it myself.